# Como Pegar A Variável De Outro Component

Tags: angular, angularjs-directives, angularjs-scope, angular-routes

Tenho a seguinte situação:

**utils-nav-usuario.component.html**

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand text-white">ESC - Sistema De Controle De Pizzaria - </a>
  <a class="navbar-brand text-white">Usuário Logado: {{loginUsuarioParam}}</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropup">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" id="dropdown10" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Login</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown10">
          <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/usuario/login" routerLinkActive="active">Sair</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**utils-nav-usuario.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-utils-nav-usuario',
  templateUrl: './utils-nav-usuario.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./utils-nav-usuario.component.css']
})
export class UtilsNavUsuarioComponent {

  loginUsuarioParam : string;

}
```

Tenho essa variável em meu `Component` e preciso ler essa variável em diversas partes do programa, mas como eu faço pra ler em outro `Component` por exemplo no exemplo abaixo.

**pedido-avulso-create.component.ts**

```
  abrirCaixa() {

    this.caixa.codigoUsuario = this.loginUsuarioParam;

    this.caixaService.saveCaixa(this.caixa)
    .subscribe (
      data => {
        if (data.status == 200) {
          this.toastr.success("Pedido Avulso", "Pedido Avulso Alterado Com Sucesso.");

        }
      },
      error => {
        if (error.status == 0) {
          this.toastr.error("Pedido Avulso", "Sem Conexão Com O WebService.");
        } else {
          this.error = error.json();
          this.toastr.error("Pedido Avulso", this.error.message); 
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Tenho esse método acima que está em outro `Component` é quero ler para jogar nessa classe alguém tem ideia como eu faço isso, eu tive a ideia de mudar esse `nav` como é usado em todas as telas criar um `Module` para ele mas agora não sei como usar a variável que está lá.

Answer (score 1):

Existem duas possibilidades:

A primeira é se o componente que você quer ler a variável é filho do componente que tem a variável loginUsuarioParam (UtilsNavUsuarioComponent). Nesse caso você declara a variável loginUsuarioParam como @Input() no componente filho:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-pedido-avulso-create',
  templateUrl: './pedido-avulso-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pedido-avulso-create.component.css']
})
export class UtilsPedidoAvulsoCreateComponent {
  /* você pode declarar um valor padrão caso a variável não seja declarada no componente */
  Input() loginUsuarioParam = '';

}
```

E a outra opção é salvar em uma variável global ou no localStorage.

Comment: Vou testar aqui pra ver se vai funcionar.

Comment: Beleza, qualquer coisa avisa aqui ;)

Comment: Deu meio certo, mais não fico muito legal não, pensei que ia funcionar meio diferente, porque em cada tela eu vou ter que fazer a mesma coisa e fica passando o parâmetro e criando um input() em cada Component.

Comment: acabei utlizando o LocalStorage que você falou, resolveu bem o problema que eu tinha, muito obrigado.

Comment: Que bom, eu acredito que dependendo da situação seja melhor usar @Input() ou um controlador de estados ngstore.